# How to display sum result on each line of Fibonacci Series using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I'm doing a fibonacci series using javascript. I've tried to show the result(var3) of var1 + var2 like the one on my code, but it seems that the answer on each line is not correct.

Look at the output:

[image]

and this is what I want to show:

[image]

I've tried a lot of tricks, but still the result is incorrect.

Here's my code on Javascript:

```
function fib() {
    var var1 = -1;
    var var2 = 1;
    var var3;
    var var4 = 0;

    var num = prompt("Enter the limit to generate fibonacci no", 0);

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        var3 = var1 + var2;
        var1 = var2;
        var2 = var3;
        var4 += var3;

        document.write(var3 + "---------------> ");
        document.write(var1 + "+" + var2 + "<br/>");
    }
    document.write("<br/>" + var4);
}
```

on HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="fib" onclick="fib()"/>
```

Comment: I don't see any pattern what you want, I can just print the steps, and there is no step such `0+0=0` the step to get `0` is `-1+1=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i did, i think it will solve your problem

```
function fib()
        {
            var var1 = 0;
            var var2 = 0;
            var var3 = 0;
            var var4 = 1;
            var flag = 0;

            var num = prompt("Enter the limit to generate fibonacci no", 0);

            for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    document.write(var3 + "---------------> ");
                    document.write(var1 + "+" + var2 + "<br/>");
                    var2 = var4;
                    flag = 1;
                    vars = var1 + var2;
                    document.write(vars + "---------------> ");
                    document.write(var1 + "+" + var2 + "<br/>");

                }
                var3 = var1 + var2;
                if (flag > 0)
                {
                    document.write(var3 + "---------------> ");
                    document.write(var1 + "+" + var2 + "<br/>");
                }
                var1 = var2;
                var2 = var3;
                var4 += var3;
                flag = 2;
            }
            document.write("<br/>" + var4);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop do something like bellow. Problem was after updating the values you are saying `document.write` so It is printing updated values.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        var3 = var1 + var2;
        document.write(var3 + "---------------> ");
        document.write(var1 + "+" + var2 + "<br/>");
        var1 = var2;
        var2 = var3;
        var4 += var3;


    }
```

output

```
0---------------> -1+1
1---------------> 1+0
1---------------> 0+1
2---------------> 1+1
3---------------> 1+2
5---------------> 2+3
8---------------> 3+5
13---------------> 5+8

33
```

Comment: That's cool, but is there's a way to show the output like what I want? Thanks!